# android app notification push doesn't work

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent, preference

I was trying to implement a push notification in my android app. Ideally, there should be a notification showing on the top of the screen with my customized title and icon when a new message arrives, if the preference is turned on. But nothing happened when I received new messages. I was running the emulator (because I don't have a device with SIM card) to send and receive messages, and the version was Android 5.0.1, API 21.

Here's my code for the notification:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static String TAG = "**SmsReceiver**";
private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

private static final int NOTIFY_CODE = 1;
private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 3;
private static int SMS_SENT_CODE = 2;

final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Received SMS: " + intent);

    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            SmsMessage[] messages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);

            // notifications and auto-reply
            for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                notification(context, message);
            }

        }
    }
}
private void notification(Context context, SmsMessage message) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    // determine whether to push notification or not
    boolean pushNotification = prefs.getBoolean("pref_push_notification",true);
    if (pushNotification) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("New Message from: "+message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress())
                    .setContentText(message.getDisplayMessageBody())
                    .setVibrate(new long[] {0,500,500,500})
                    .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    // add a history stack from the parent stack

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(NOTIFY_CODE,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // handle click notification
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        // ask the system whether to show notification
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID,builder.build());
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(context,"You got a message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Any ideas of what was wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you keep alive your SMS Receiver?

Comment: Hi @UğurB, I am not sure what you mean by "keep alive". The data retrieved from SmsReceiver is put in a Listview contained in the MainActivity. When a new message is received, the list will update itself.

Comment: have you declared intent for sms_received action in the manifest? it will listen whenever an sms received and invoke your SMSReceiver.

Comment: @UğurB I put  <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filer>
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> in manifest.xml, is it correct?

Comment: That manifest should be correct. Ive used telephony and smsreceiver is always alive

Comment: 1 check ur sharedprefs. In fact, get rid of the if statement for now since if it is null then you wont get notified

Comment: 2 i am not sure how it works on emulator, but on device under settings you must make sure that notifications for that app is allowed

Comment: 3 this isnt super relevant to your bug, but you should make your notification ids different for text notification so each one is unique. Otherwise each will just repllace the previous one

Comment: your code seems ok. it may be emulator problem as you said. i recommend use log outputs for all the conditions inside onReceive(), and if conditions. so you can get an idea if your intent fires and get a message correctly.